# Configure Apache2.4 as "secure scheme"

Tags: apache, tomcat, outlook-restapi

I have a java web application which I am trying to host on a home computer running windows server 2012. I have configured it so that Apache and Tomcat communicate with each other and I am able to access the website fine. The issue arrises when the form that I built asks the user to log in to Microsoft for Outlook REST API. After logging in, microsoft gives an error and will not redirect, because it is only compatible with a "secure scheme". How can I set up my server to be a "secure scheme"? I included a screen shot of the error page:
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Secure Scheme = "HTTPS". You need to secure your site with an SSL certificate.